# writing jquery plugin, need to let page know code has executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-frontend

I'm attempting to build my first jquery plugin. It's a simple drag-and-drop game. Basically the plugin does this:

1. Identify a group of child divs under the parent div
2. apply some styling to those child divs and randomize their
   order.
3. apply a .draggable function to each child div.
4. identify the target div(s) and add .droppable function(s) to them.
5. When a draggable is placed on a droppable, make sure it's the correct draggable for that droppable.
6. after all the draggables have been placed on the correct
   droppables, let the player know they've finished the game.

what I need to do now is let the page know that #6 has happened, so that if I wanted to animate something or fire off another function, it will wait until that point.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out what exactly it is that I need to learn. Would what I'm after be an event listener? Something else? I've got a small if statement for #6:

```
if (score === dragsTotal) {
    $(dragsCont).append("<div style='font-weight:bold;text-align:center'>" + settings.finishText + "</div>");
    }
```

so I'm sure that's where, whatever-it-is-that-i-need-to-learn has to go. I thought that all I might need is a boolean, but I don't know how to let the page know what that boolean *is* or that it's changed.

If it's needed, the codepen here: http://codepen.io/kking/pen/YqXGaw/

Comment: I would recommend looking into custom events, defined and triggered by you at the correct times. https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/

Answer (score 0):

I'd hook in to the drop event. Each time they drop one, check them all to see if they're finished yet.